# ReactJS babel script is not dispaying content

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently experimenting with ReactJS and I am not sure why this html page is not displaying any text for the input control (and also the control width is zero).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Textbox example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/example.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
  <form id="mainform">
  </form>
 </div>
    <script src="../build/react.js"></script>
    <script src="../build/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
 
  function textbox(props) {
   return (<input type='text' value={props.value} class='form-control' />);   
  }
  
  function component() {
   return (<div class='component'></div>);
  } 
  
  ReactDOM.render(
   <textbox value="Hello World" />,      
   document.getElementById('mainform')
  );  
   
   
 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using capitalized names for your components. `function Textbox(props)` and `<Textbox value="Hello World" />,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things you need to change:

*Change `doctype` to `DOCTYPE`.

*Name of `react` component should start with **upper case**, otherwise it will be treated as `HTML` element.

*Don't include `react` and `react-dom` reference like this:

```
<script src="../build/react.js"></script>
<script src="../build/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Include the reference in `HTML` file, like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Or if you are maintaining different files then import it on the top of the file.

Check the working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Textbox example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/example.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
      <form id="mainform">
      </form>
     </div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/babel">
 
      function Textbox(props) {
       return (<input type='text' value={props.value} class='form-control' />);   
      }
      
      function Components() {
       return (<div class='component'></div>);
      } 
      
      ReactDOM.render(
       <Textbox value="Hello World" />,      
       document.getElementById('mainform')
      );   
     </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Capitalizing did the trick. did not had to change anything else.